# Алгоритм GIOTTO для укладки графов

Tags: графы

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно ознакомится с алгоритмом GIOTTO?

Comment: как бы тут https://www.google.com/search?biw=1385&bih=757&ei=q5cUXtYbyNDpBKvxtfgE&q=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC+GIOTTO&oq=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC+GIOTTO&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.2292324.2292324..2292654...0.2..0.0.0.......0....2j1..gws-wiz.53wBJsNzav8&ved=0ahUKEwiWnZS62_HmAhVIaJoKHat4DU8Q4dUDCAo&uact=5

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но проблема в том, что ни в одном из русскоязычных источников я не нашел детального описания алгоритма. Если точнее: некоторые шаги просто не поясняются и даже не указывается ссылка где можно это изучить. В англоязычных источниках немного иначе: я вовсе не нашел описание данного алгоритма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно ситуация такая. GIOTTO был придуман на заре человечества (1995-1997).

Собственно он подробно описан авторами в книге [Battista G., Eades P., Tamassia R., Tollis I. Graph Drawing. Algorithms for the Visualization of Graphs. New Jersey: Prentice Hall, 1999.](https://epdf.pub/graph-drawing-algorithms-for-the-visualization-of-graphs.html) Интересно, что название Giotto там не встречается, ищите Algorithm N, например Algorithm 3. В этой книге и содержится ответ на ваш вопрос.

В 2000 была создана библиотека [AGD: A Library ofAlgorithms for Graph Drawing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.3762&rep=rep1&type=pdf), с реализацией алгоритма но она канула в Лету.

Есть бакалаврская работа [М. А. Коротков](http://is.ifmo.ru/diploma-theses/mkorotkov-bachelor.pdf)(2005), в которой автор применил алгоритм к отрисовке UML диаграмм и даже есть [библиотека](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unimod/files/).

Что имеем в итоге: алгоритм Giotto старый и имеет сейчас теоретическое значение.

Есть [пример](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualising-high-dimensional-data-with-giotto-mapper-897fcdb575d7) визуализации графа с помощью giotto-learning, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не совсем то, что нужно. (оказывается Giotto популярное итальянское слово\имя, художник Джотто)

Разработаны более современные [алгоритмы визуализации графов на плоскости](http://Asurveyoftwo-dimensionalgraphlayout%20techniques%20for%20informationvisualisation).

Собственно после 2005-2006 года про giotto нет публикаций, так как он представляет более теоретический интерес, как показала практика.

Казалось бы все печально. НО. Мы же в интернете. Автор алгоритма Giuseppe Di Battista на своей [страничке](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~compunet/www/view/person.php?id=gdb) приводит ссылку на свою [графическую библиотеку рисования графов](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~compunet/www/view/tool.php?id=gdt). Думаю знакомство с ней вам поможет.

Comment: Большое спасибо